# C, getc/fgetc - terminal null

Tags: c, file, fgetc, null-terminated

I'm writing program that counts words in C, I know I can do this simply with fscanf. But I'm using getc.

I have file like this:

> One two three four five.

I'm reading chars in while loop and breaking point is when I reach terminal null.

Will `c = fgetc(input);` or `c = getc(input);` set `c  = '\0';` after One_ and after two_ etc.?

Comment: Why don't you try it? Read one character at a time and print its value. You might also want to read e.g. [this `fgetc` and `getc` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc).

Comment: Of course I tried it. I'm getting segfault in that loop because I access array out of bounds. I access array out of bounds because c == '\0' don't happen. I am asking this question however because I'm not certain on this.

Comment: Files are not null-terminated.

Comment: Accessing *what* array? Can you maybe create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the failing program and show us? It will be much easier to help you then. And *do* read the reference to see what the function returns.

Comment: I've read man page. I'm simply asking question EOF just answered. Just that, nothing more. If you know answer to my question why don't you just say it. I'm not asking you to debug my program.

Comment: If you read the manpage for `getc()`, you might have read something like `fgetc() reads the next character from  stream  and  returns  it  as  an unsigned char cast to an int, or EOF on end of file or error.
getc()  is equivalent to fgetc() except that it may be implemented as a macro which evaluates stream more than once.` , which is why you should take care to treat the return value as an `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm obviously missing something, where is answer to my question in paragraph you copied?

Comment: No, it will not set `c` to `'\0'` unless that is the next character in the file. If it is a text file, very unlikely. As @EOF has said, the eponymous `EOF` indicates the end of file, and you must read the character into an `int` type variable, not a `char` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a return value of a function like `getc()` is `EOF` which is -1,then you have reached the end of file.try this code to count words:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int WordCount(FILE *file);

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file;
    if(fopen_s(&file,"file.txt","r")) {
        return 1;
    }
    int n = WordCount(file);
    printf("number of words is %d\n", n);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}

int WordCount(FILE *file)
{
    bool init = 0;
    int count = 0, c;
    while((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        if(c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t') {
            init = 1;
        }
        else {
            if(init) {
                count++;
                init = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if(init)
        return (count + 1);
    else
        return count;
}
```